# Using pointers to objects as function arguments

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am currently working on a rudimentary simulator for the game Boggle, and right now I have gotten to the point where I need to use pointers to an object in a function call. However, I am unsure of how to do this, and thus far my search on this site and elsewhere has not proved fruitful, seeing as from what I have seen the questions have not been about pointers to objects. The following is my code for the function being called from a class, the initialization of the objects, and my attempted function calls. The setAdjacency function is found in the class boggleNode.

```
void setAdjacency(boggleNode * topleft = NULL, boggleNode * top = NULL,    boggleNode * topright = NULL, 
boggleNode * left = NULL, boggleNode * right = NULL, boggleNode *  botleft = NULL, boggleNode *  bot = NULL, boggleNode *  botright = NULL){
    adjacency[0] = topleft;
    adjacency[1] = top;
    adjacency[2] = topright;
    adjacency[3] = left;
    adjacency[4] = right;
    adjacency[5] = botleft;
    adjacency[6] = bot;
    adjacency[7] = botright;             //For keeping track of which nodes  are adjacent to which other ones. 
}
```

These are the private variables in boggleNode:

```
private:
boggleNode * adjacency[8];
char letter;
bool isUsed;
```

"Board" is defined as follows:

```
boggleNode * board = new boggleNode[16];
```

And finally, here is where I attempt to call the adjacency function in my main function:

```
board[0].setAdjacency(board[1], board[4], board[5]);
```

I am aware that currently the arguments in this function call are references, whereas they are supposed to be pointers in the function definition. How do I get the function call and the function definition to align properly?

Comment: Do you have a compiler error you can post?

Comment: `I am aware that currently the arguments in this function call are references` I don't see references in that call.  You are passing `boggleNode` instances.  Maybe you are getting confused with `Java`?

Answer (score 1):

The value of a pointer to object is the address of the object. To get the address of the object, you need to use the "addressof" operator: `&`

```
board[0].setAdjacency(&board[1], &board[4], &board[5]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I got some help from a friend of mine, and I figured out the answer. I needed to use "addressof" operator plus extra parentheses (for instance, &(board[0]) ).